# InvalidArgument: 400 Cannot convert an array value in an array value

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I have a dictionary that contains two lists of lists presented as: dictionary =

```
{'Position': [['Teaching', '10'],
  ['Supervisor', '3']]],
 'Major': [['Arts', '1'],
  ['Accounting', '6']]}
```

I want to add these to firestore where the first element of the list is the "field name" and second element is value.

The output should look like this:

```
Position (map)
         Teaching : 10
         Supervisor : 3
Major (map)
         Arts : 1
         Accounting:6
```

My code so far:

```
default = {'Position':{}, 'Major':{}}
db.collection(u'coll').document(u'info').collection(u'colname').set(default)


storeReference = db.collection(u'coll').document(u'info').collection(u'colname')

storeReference.set({dictionaryy}, merge=True)
```

Error:

> InvalidArgument: 400 Cannot convert an array value in an array value.

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `update({dictionary}, merge=True)` instead of `set`?

As I understand it, `set` is for when an item doesn't exist yet, but I believe you've already created it with `set(default)`...

And I see that `storeReference` references the collection and not the document.

Lastly, I think you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54785637/cloud-functions-error-cannot-convert-an-array-value-in-an-array-value), because it's from last year and it still applies. it should be `{['Teaching','10'],['Supervisor','3']}` and not `[['Teaching','10'],['Supervisor','3']]`. That's what it means by convert an array value in an array value (convert the value in an array into its own array within the array, no nesting)