# Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot convert an array value in an array value

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to do a batch update for my field which has an array type. My code is as shown below (using typescript for firebase cloud function for this case):

```
const channelRefs = await admin.firestore().collection("channels").where("participants", "array-contains", AA).get();
const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
channelRefs.docs.forEach((doc) => {
  const channelDocRef = admin.firestore().collection("channels").doc(channelID);
  batch.update(channelDocRef, {"photoURL":[xx, yy]});
}
await batch.commit();
```

But there is an error message in the logs as shown:

> Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot convert an array value in an array
> value.

I think the likely cause of the error is the code where I update the array which is

```
batch.update(channelDocRef, {"photoURL":[xx, yy]});
```

Any suggestion on an array field with a new set of data? Thanks

---edit below----

My data is as shown below:

```
User
—Photo(array)
    —photo1(string)
    —photo2(string)
```

What I want is to replace photo1 with something else so what I did was to just replace the whole array with

```
db.collection("users").doc(doc.id).update({photo: [photo3,photo1]});
```

since I can't simply replace the first item in the array

Comment: Can you mention on which line of the code you are getting the error?

Comment: hi @Prabir, I have updated the the line of code on top

Comment: Seems like you are having the same issue as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54785637/cloud-functions-error-cannot-convert-an-array-value-in-an-array-value). The answer to the question is that nested arrays are not supported in Cloud Firestore. Can you please add the Firestore Database Structure also, which will make us understand the issue better?

Comment: hi @Prabir, sorry for the late reply. But I've added in the database structure above.

Comment: hi @Prabir, after some troubleshooting, I managed to get it to work. Thanks anyways